# Select child nodes, but ignore non-elements with XPath?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xpath

Given the following XML document for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<UrdaObject>
  <Date>
    <Year>2011</Year>
    <Month>5</Month>
    <Day>18</Day>
    <Hours>8</Hours>
    <Minutes>47</Minutes>
    <Seconds>36</Seconds>
  </Date>
  <random_value>24</random_value>
</UrdaObject>
```

And the understanding the `child::node() - Selects all child nodes of the current node` how would I create an `XPath` (starting from the root) that would select all child nodes EXCEPT text, comments, and other **things that are NOT elements**. For example, when using this code to create a tree view in WPF:

```
// x is some XmlDocument, xmlTree is my WPF TreeView
XmlDataProvider provider = new XmlDataProvider();
provider.Document = x;
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = provider;
binding.XPath = "child::node()";
xmlTree.SetBinding(TreeView.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

How would I go about creating my XPath statement so I build a treeview with nodes going all the way down and stopping before the raw text? For example it would generate a view of:

```
UrdaObject
  Date
    Year
...
```

Instead of...

```
UrdaObject
  Date
    Year
      2011 (Don't want this!)
...
```

The sample XML files is just for me to explain my situation. The expression should be able to navigate *any* valid XML file and pull the elements, but not the individual text.

---

**How did we fix this?** I had switched all references of `child::node()` to `child::*`. However, I had NOT corrected one line in my XAML, which was pulling `child::node()`. Correcting this line made the application behave correctly... and made me feel silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`child::node()` finds all child nodes. `child::*` finds all *element* nodes.

Comment: I had tried that earlier, but the child::* also turned up the individual text entries inside the C# TreeView (given the chunk of code above) but the binding keeps access the text view as if it was an element and I can seem to explain it.

Comment: ...I take back my comment from above. This fixed it, here's why: I had built the query correctly, but a silly mistake in one of my templates inside my XAML was still trying to pull ALL elements using the `node()` property. Correcting this issue caused the treeview to work correctly. Wow do I feel silly for missing that...

Answer (score 2):

it's as simple as `*`.

(that gets immediate children, however; if you want all descendant elements, it would be `descendant::*`)

Answer (score 1):

`child::*` will exclude text nodes and leave only element nodes

`child::text()` will include only text nodes

`child::node()` will include both element and text nodes

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths

Comment: Is there a way I can explicitly exclude text nodes? I think the issue is the TreeView is traversing the XML file, and is still pulling out the single text nodes and adding them, even when using `child::*`

Comment: I'm a fool, explanation above. However I had to give the answer to lonesomeday since he had a earlier timestamp.

Comment: I think you're confusing what the XPath selects with how the TreeView displays it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but could it be done this way?

```
var doc =XDocument.Parse(@"

<UrdaObject>
  <Date>
    <Year>2011</Year>
    <Month>5</Month>
    <Day>18</Day>
    <Hours>8</Hours>
    <Minutes>47</Minutes>
    <Seconds>36</Seconds>
  </Date>
  <random_value>24</random_value>
</UrdaObject>
");



        var query = from s in doc.Descendants()
                    select s.Name;


        foreach (var name in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
```

Comment: 1) I'm not using XDocument in this project, 2) I'm somewhat limited to using XPath to get the result I need, or some prior XML manipulation for the TreeView.