# Bind XSD to treeview Only <xs:element and <xs:sequence nodes and show their name

Tags: wpf, xaml, xsd, tree, treeview

I am trying the solution provided here 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/16a91381-0714-4ba1-aff0-7f3b6483b282/populate-a-treeview-from-xsd-file-in-wpf?forum=wpf
Take only xs:element and xs:sequence nodes and exclude all other nodes(xs:complexType>) etc.
and need out come like:

```
>TypedDataSet
 >Orders
     >OrderID
     >OrderTypeID
     >OrderDate
>OrderTypes
     >OrderTypeID
     >OrderTypeName
     >Rank
```

I tried using Chile::* and Child::node() but it is taking all nodes including complextype and other and getting "node text"(xs:complexType, xs:element) not node name

referred this as well :[Select child nodes, but ignore non-elements with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048168/select-child-nodes-but-ignore-non-elements-with-xpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` can be used to filter elements, and then a postfix predicate to filter by element name:

```
*[node-name() = (
           xs:QName("xs:element"),
           xs:QName("xs:sequence")
         )]
```